# Android softkeyboard popup a mini keyboard when press some keys by using remote controller

Tags: java

I am developing a soft keyboard for Set-Top Box now.
My function is when I press enter key on TV remote controller, it can popup a mini keyboard above the soft keyboard.

I capture a part of my program for your reference.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

```js
 @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ABS.onCreateInputView");
        inputView = (SoftKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input,null);
        inputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);       
        return inputView;
    }

@Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "ABS.onStartInputView");
        super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);

        // Reset editor and candidates when the input-view is just being started.
        editor.start(attribute.inputType);
        clearCandidates();
        effect.reset();

        keyboardSwitch.initializeKeyboard(getMaxWidth());
        // Select a keyboard based on the input type of the editing field.
        keyboardSwitch.onStartInput(attribute.inputType);
        bindKeyboardToInputView();
    }

private void bindKeyboardToInputView() {
        if (inputView != null) {
            // Bind the selected keyboard to the input view.
            inputView.setKeyboard(keyboardSwitch.getCurrentKeyboard());
            updateCursorCapsToInputView();
            check_focus(); // focus on keyboard 
        }
    }

@Override
  public void setKeyboard(Keyboard keyboard) {
    if (keyboard instanceof SoftKeyboard) {
      boolean escape = hasEscape();
      currentKeyboard = (SoftKeyboard) keyboard;      
      currentKeyboard.updateStickyKeys();
      currentKeyboard.setEscape(escape);
           
    }
    super.setKeyboard(keyboard);
  }
```